# How to pass and get variables in the url in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I send variables in the URL using CodeIgniter. I already read some forums, but I didn't find the correct syntax for it.

Here is the format I want to have in the URL.

http://localhost/acc/index.php/Jev/entryAccount/2016-08-0042

Comment: it can be like this
'base_url('controller/method/action');'

Comment: where do i put it sir?

Comment: you can put in a link <a href="<?php echo base_url('controller/method/action'); ?>">Link</a>

Comment: Thank you sir.. I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

first you put your variables in query string like this:

```
redirect('mycontroler/senddata/'.$name.'/'.$email);
```

In controler receive parameters in this way:

```
public function senddata($name,$email)
{
   // do you stuff here
}
```

Or to receive parameter you can use:

```
$this->uri->segment(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the documentation carefully first. In Codeigniter or any other MVC the url generally follows this rule `example.com/class/function/ID`. In your case the data `2016-08-0042` will automatically be available as a parameter to the `entryAccount` method in the `Jev` class.